# Dynamic IDs in mark up

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I am iterating some mark up as below

```
For Each drCustMsg As DataRow In dtCustMsg.Rows
     Dim strMsgId As String = drCustMsg.Item("MsgId")
     %>
        <table border="0" runat="server" id="tblCustMsg_<%= strMsgId %>" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="shade-ml-comm">
.
.
..
.
.
.
<% Next%>
```

however `id="tblCustMsg_<%= strMsgId %>"` doesn't render properly. It gives me parser error

> 'tblCustMsg_<%= strMsgId %>' is not a valid identifier.

Comment: Remove the `runat="server"` attribute.

Comment: @VDWWD perfect. Thanks

Comment: Wouldn't adding `clientidmode="static"` work here too? Or is that for ASP controls only?